# How do I set the content search web part to return no results by default?

Tags: search, search-results, content-search-web-part

I have a content search web part that is optional to use.  If a user finds an item through the filtered navigation I don't want them to see the content search web part.  If they use the search box I want the web part to show the appropriate search results.  I can get the web part to get the correct results from the correct source, but now it defaults to showing the items.  Is there a way I can make the default show no items and then still run the correct search when a value is used in the search box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that comes to my mind is using jQuery. On page load check if the search box has any values, based on that Show/Hide the results. Something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var searchValue = jQuery('#searchboxid').val();
    if(searchValue == null || searchValue == '' || searchValue == 'Search...') {
        jQuery('#webpartid').hide();
    }
});
```

You can find the `searchboxid` and `webpartid` using browser developer tools.

**Edit**

Handling key events in Search Box

```
jQuery('#ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_SmallSearchInputBox1_csr_sbox').keyup(function(e){
    var code = e.which;
    if(code==32||code==13||code==188||code==186) {
        //If required you can check if the box is empty
        //Handle backspace etc.
        jQuery('#webpartid').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, there isn't a refresh or page navigation when you search for a term so the web part stays hidden.

Comment: @Jordan in that case on page load you should hide the webpart using jQuery and then hook an onchange event handler on the search box and then show it.

Comment: I put an onchange event on my '#searchboxid' and it doesn't trigger my function when I search.

Comment: @Jordan I have updated my answer. I tried it on my dev site and its working as expected. You should change the `#id`

Comment: This does work.  Is there a way to change it on submit that you know of?  Somehow to check when the .val() changes but obviously not an onchange handler as that didn't work.

Comment: @Jordan I updated my answer to check if enter key is pressed

Comment: Or in a perfect world if you could incremental search in SharePoint that would be cool too.. That's a bit off topic though.

Comment: The update works as expected. Thanks for the help!